# Select highest value from column and corresponding value from another column in multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

[image: Source table with data]

I want to return the group which has the highest value in the columns Value1, Value2, Value3 as well as their name and numerical ID for the name. I do not know where to start since I have little SQL and Google Sheets experience. Preferably the solution would be in Google Sheets but I am open to other software alternatives. Just a pointer in the right direction would be very helpful.

[Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a0v_K8pL_aLQQaxYlIZKp1MQQ2xXEBsFVjo9a9NPaYQ/edit?usp=sharing) to the spreadsheet.

[image: The wanted result]

Comment: Can you add desired output from this example?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I messed up in my post. Can't find the edit button either. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a0v_K8pL_aLQQaxYlIZKp1MQQ2xXEBsFVjo9a9NPaYQ/edit?usp=sharing) is a link the the spreadsheet. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste in **H3** cell:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:B)
```

paste in **J3** cell and drag down:

```
=QUERY(A:F, "select max(D),max(E),max(F) 
             where A="&H3&"
             label max(D)'',max(E)'',max(F)''")
```

[image: 0]

---

paste in **H3** cell:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:B)
```

paste in **J3** cell and drag to the right then drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(QUERY({$A:$F}, 
 "select max(Col"&COLUMN(D$1)&")
  where Col1="&$H3&"
  label max(Col"&COLUMN(D$1)&")''"), 
 QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN($C$2:$C), 
 "♥"&$A$2:$A&"♦"&D$2:D&"♦"&$C$2:$C, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♥")), "♦"), 
 "select Col2,Col3 
  where Col1="&$H3), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. However, is it possible to return the Group name (FIrstGroup, SecondGroup or ThirdGroup) of the highest value instead of the highest value?